# Add multiple lines to TextBlock, WPF app

Tags: wpf, list, textblock

I'm making a WPF app and I want to add strings in ingredientsList to a TextBlock. But from my code below, It seems like the Textblock regconizes only the last string in the list. How can a display all strings on my list to the text box? or any suggestion for using other control instead of a TextBlock?

```
TextBlock  txbDisplayIngredients = new  TextBlock ();   
List<string> ingredientsList = new List<string>();
for (int t = 0; t < ingredientsList.Count(); t++)
    {
        txbDisplayIngredients.Text = ingredientsList[t] + "\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're basically changing it in each iteration, and the only one you see is the last one ...

assuming you have 3 string `one`,`two`,`three`, you're running and telling it: "Oy, make it one", then "make it two", then "make it three", so it'll do it, and you'll end up with the text box saying: "three"

You want to either have all your strings as one multi line string, or use an observable collection of strings that you'll bind that textblock to.

You could also append the lines to the `Inlines` property of the `TextBlock`: more [on this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I just found out, it works if i use this:

```
txbDisplayIngredients.Inlines.Add("     + " + ingredientsList[t] + "\n");
```

Comment: o_O ?! isn't that what I've said in my answer?